# Excel hanging calculation when opened automatically using Shell command

Tags: excel, freeze, calculation, vba

I am using VBA Shell command to automate the opening of an excel file in another instance. The excel has some built in custom addins. However, whenever I open it and run calculation using `Application.Calculate`, the calculation hangs at 3-10%. The file calculates fine in two cases:

1. When opened manually.
2. When I manually press the button of a custom addin on ribbon after opening it automatically, it works fine in that case also.

I am using following code to open:

```
Set obj = oShell.exec(pathtoexcel\Excel.EXE "pathtofile\File.xls")
Set app = GetObject("File.xls").Application
Set book = app.Workbooks("File.xls")
book.Application.calculate
```

Comment: Where do you run `Application.calculate`?

Comment: I am assuming that you are running that command from Excel becuase `Application.Calculate` is not giving you an error... My question is `Why are you opening the excel file like this?`

Comment: The excel application I am using is a modified one to enhance its memory capabilities,hence using this way to use this version of excel. The application.calculate command is used after getting an object returned from Shell. The command works fine if I click the addin on ribbon manually.